# Shorten a breadcrumb with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, breadcrumbs

I have the following code for my breadcrumbs:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<a href="/index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
<a href="../../../../index.html">Level1</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
<a href="../../../index.html">Level2</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
<a href="../../index.html">Level3</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
<a href="../index.html">Level4</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
Page
```

Which produces: "Home / Level1 / Level2 / Level3 / Level4 / Page". I want to use javascript/jQuery to shorten it to "Home / Level1 [...] Page", with Home, Level1 and the Page always showing, regardless of the number of other pages. But I'm not sure how to grab the stuff inbetween.

The following will only trigger if there's more than Level1, but where do I go from here?

```
if ($('#wayfinding a').length > 2) {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, although admittedly it's not the prettiest solution:

```
if ($('#wayfinding a').length > 3) {
    var fullPath = $('#wayfinding').html(), breadcrumbs = fullPath, w = $('#wayfinding a').length;
    for (i=0;i<=w-1;i++) {
        breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.replace('</a>','QQQQQ');
        if (i==1) { breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.replace('</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;','</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;<span class="hiddenCrumbs">'); }
        if (i==w-2) { breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.replace('</a>','</a></span>'); }
        if (i==w-1) { breadcrumbs = breadcrumbs.replace(/QQQQQ/g,'</a>'); }
    }
    $('#wayfinding').html(breadcrumbs);
    $('.hiddenCrumbs').html('[...]').click(function() {
        $('#wayfinding').html(fullPath);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this a bit complex but should work:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .breadcrums 
    {
        width:500px;
    }
    .breadcrums li
    {
        list-style-type:none;
        display:inline;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var length =  $('.breadcrums li').length;
        $('.breadcrums li').each(function(n){
                if(n > 2 && n!=length-1){
                $(this).hide();
                }
            });        
        });
    </script>

<ul class="breadcrums">
<li> <a name="top"></a></li>
<li><a href="/index.html">Home</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="../../../../index.html">Level1</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="../../../index.html">Level2</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="../../index.html">Level3</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</li>
<li><a href="../index.html">Level4</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</li>
<li>Page</li>
</ul>
```

**Update 1:**
The main reason to enclose the link tag in li is to hide the / separator. Without enclosing it, I am not sure how you would get hold of that text.

Check if this version fit your needs:

```
<div class="wayfinding">
<a name="top"></a>
<a href="/index.html">Home</a><span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
<a href="../../../../index.html">Level1</a><span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
<a href="../../../index.html">Level2 </a><span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
<a href="../../index.html">Level3 </a><span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
<a href="../index.html">Level4 </a><span>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>
Page
</div>

var length = $('.wayfinding a').length;
            $('.wayfinding a').each(function (n) {
                if (n > 2 && n != length) {
                    $(this).next().hide();
                    $(this).hide();
                }
                if (n == 2) {
                     $(this).next().after('<span>[...]&nbsp;/&nbsp;</span>');
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is on the right track, but I'm afraid I'm unable to edit the HTML output. It's given me some ideas tho...

Answer (score 0):

Can you add selectors or modify the HTML at all? Wrapping each level of breadcrumb would make this  much easier to accomplish.

Altered HTML

```
<div id="wayfinding">
    <a name="top"></a>
    <div class="level"><a href="/index.html">Home</a></div>
    <div class="level"><a href="../../../../index.html">Level1</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="level"><a href="../../../index.html">Level2</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="level"><a href="../../index.html">Level3</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="level"><a href="../index.html">Level4</a>&nbsp;/&nbsp;</div>
    Page
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#wayfinding .level:not(:first)').remove();
$('#wayfinding .level:last').after('[...]');
```